# ¿Eventos extendidos para botones en HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5, arduino

Tengo que registrar cuando un usuario mantiene presionado un botón para un control de un robot automóvil *WiFi*, ¿qué opciones me podrían dar para implementar en *Javascript* con *HTML5*?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas como preguntar primero,si puedes subir fragmentos del código que has intentado hasta ahora para que los usuarios puedan entender tu problema mas fácil

Answer (score -1):

Aquí puedes encontrar documentación sobre los eventos de botones
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

```
<button id="prueba"></button>


document.getElementById("prueba").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {    
event.target.innerHTML = "Conteo de Clicks: " + event.detail;
}, false);
```

Comment: La pregunta no es clara , no debes precipitarte a contestar hasta que la pregunta sea clara. La pregunta no tiene fragmentos de código ni ejemplos de los que se ha realizado hasta ahora, la pregunta tiene objetivos muy amplios, debes esperar a que la pregunta sea modificada o clara para dar solución

Comment: Gracias por responder, soy nuevo, me referia a un boton con la etiqueta <button> ya que investigando no he encontrado que registren eventos onPressed